# Is there a usb device indicator (that ejects it) that works with Lubuntu 16.10?

Tags: lubuntu, indicator

I have a computer that many people in my family use. For some, it is hard to learn to eject usb devices in the file manager.
Is there a usb indicator that works with Lubuntu 16.10? It would be more friendly to them, since most have used windows in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are such indicators. I've written one myself, originally for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it has been tested by multiple users on Ubuntu MATE, Lubuntu, and XFCE. While originally intended for checking disk usage, it also allows opening directories and unmounting the filesystems:

[image]

You can install it via two PPAs, one is dedicated to the indicator itself, the other is to all the indicators I write in general.

Steps to installing from my personal PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:1047481448-2/sergkolo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install udisks-indicator
```

Steps to install from the team PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:udisks-indicator-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install udisks-indicator
```

NOTE: that the indicator relies on `zenity` so you need that installed as well.

---

There are other alternatives,too. In particular there is `indicator-diskman` , made by Tony George. However, his project isn't supporting Yakety (16.10). I've contacted the developer to update his PPA and once they do I will update my answer. For now, one can grab `.deb` [package for amd64 architecture](https://code.launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/indicator-diskman_17.1~14~ubuntu17.04.1_amd64.deb) from the repository itself, and install it manually.

**Update**: As promised, the answer is being updated to include Tony George's `indicator-diskman`, who updated the PPA to include Yakety to the list of supported versions.

The indicator-diskman is more minimalistic, but provides exactly same features in a more concise way.

[image]

Installation commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-diskman
```